# MS Access table write conflict

Tags: ms-access

I have some MS Access application linked with MySQL database.
In some tables, some rows are able to update successfully, but some rows when try to update it show error write conflict.

Below is one of the table structure that occur this error

## Name    Type    Null    Default Extra

1   task_id int(11) No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2   employee_code   varchar(50) Yes     NULL
3   project_code    varchar(50) Yes     NULL
4   revision_no varchar(50) Yes     NULL
5   task_code   varchar(50) Yes     NULL
6   task    varchar(1000)   Yes     NULL
7   plan_complete_date  date    Yes     NULL
8   actual_complete_date    date    Yes     NULL
9   complete    tinyint(4)  Yes     0
10  score_kpi   tinyint(4)  Yes     0
11  status  varchar(50) Yes     NULL
12  remark  varchar(1000)   Yes     NULL
13  verify_by_person    varchar(255)    Yes     NULL
14  verify_by_department    varchar(255)    Yes     NULL
15  isdelete    tinyint(4)  Yes     0

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i found the problem.
Some of my date field have value of 0000-00-00, update them to null or empty solve the error.

Still im not putting timestamp field in my tables.

Anyway, thank BitAccesser for the information. Learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

There is no timestamp field!

Is "return matching rows instead of affected" activated in ODCB Connection?

You meet the conditions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft-access.html ?